# Why parentheses are required for reference to array in function parameters?

Tags: c++

I have a homework in university. I need to change some elements' positions in an array inside an external function, but initialise then in the main function.

Here is the code:

```
template <int K>
void g(int (&X)[K][K]) {/*some code here*/}

int main() {
  int T[8][8];
  g(T);
  // some more code...
  return 0;
}
```

The question is why are parentheses are required for reference in this case?
When I try to write this parameter without them

```
template <int K>
void g(int &X[K][K]) {/*some code here*/}
```

I get an error `"Unacceptable array of references" (error 2234).` in the declaration of `g`.

Comment: No, he is talking about `(&X)`.

Comment: To handle precedence of grammar/parsing.

Comment: Btw, the error is quite self-explanatory. Reference to array vs array of references.

Comment: Why you don't just use pointers like: `function(int *arr)` ?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier: using more typed type is safer (we got and restrict the size `K` here).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I always use pointers, for me is easier. But I got the idea of safety here

Comment: Without parenthesis the [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is `int &((X[K])[K])`. That's an illegal array of arrays of references to `int`s. `int (&X)[K][K]` is a reference to an array of arrays of `int`s.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use a type alias: `using Array2D = int[K][K]; void g(Array2D & items)` or even without extra declaration using a [little library](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Straight-Declarations) `ref<array<K, array<K, int>>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses are needed to disambiguate between applying the reference "operator"<sup>1</sup> on the array itself versus on the type of the element.

Note that reference types are not valid element type for an array, so `T &identifier[length]` is never valid. Pointers are valid element types, and `T *identifier[length]` is array of pointers while `T (*identifier)[length]` is pointer to an array and `T *(&identifier)[length]` is a reference to an array of pointers.

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the grammar calls the token a `ptr-operator`, but it is neither an operator nor limited to a pointer declaration.

Comment: nitpicking: not really to "disambiguate". Without the brackets, its not ambiguous, but due to precedence its a array of references

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that is literally what "disambiguate" means. If the brackets weren't required, it would have been ambiguous. Thus the brackets disambiguate it.

Comment: @Ayxan Ah ok, makes sense if you read the question as "why are the rules the way they are"

Comment: I was also thinking that without the parentheses, `X` would, without ambiguity, be an array of references and declaring `X` as different type (as done with the parentheses) does therefore not resolve any ambiguity. :)